# Refresh Controll para de funcionar se listView sair da tela

Tags: android, listview, react-native

Eu estou tentando receber uma lista de itens do Firebase, incluindo imagens, que vão ser renderizadas em uma ListView.

Mas o problema é que quando a ListView fica maior do que a tela, então o RefreshControl não funciona mais.

[Funcionando, com uma lista cheia "dentro" da tela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MQap.png)

[Não funcionando, se puxado aparece esse efeito de "limite"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2vcb.png)

---

### Render method

```
   <View contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ListView
      enableEmptySections
      dataSource={this.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
      }
    />
  </View>
```

---

```
  onRefresh() {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true });
    this.props.eventsFetch();
  }
```

---

Tentei até usando `FlatList` mas nem assim vai.

Comment: nesse vídeo o cara usa o Refresh numa ListView, veja se vc consegue fazer algo parecido: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScaXi00HRg0

Comment: ja tentou colocar um `style={{flex:1}}` na sua `ListView`?

Comment: Outro detalhe `contentContainerStyle` é uma prop da `ListView` portanto essa prop na `View` nao vai ter efeito nenhum.

Comment: Tentei colocar `style={{ flex: 1 }}` na minha `ListView` mas não adiantou. Ja tentei tirar o `contentContainerStyle` e colocar na `ListView` tambem, não funcionou

Comment: Já tentou usar o `ScrollView` no lugar?

Comment: Já, e da o mesmo problema, eu dei um jeito usando um snapshot do firebase, quando houver alteração, mostra um botão pra fazer o refresh